# nextJs ServerSideProps and rendering the HTML for SEO

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Here is the issue I am having. I am trying to have the Ag-grid render it's html output using NextJS getServerSideProps. However, when I view the source code, it doesn't appear to have any of the HTML rendered for SEO purposes. If I go ahead and output the "staff" array to a div then the HTML output is viewable in the source code so at least I know the function is working. Is there something I need to do to have AGGridReact render its contents?

```
 export default function Home({ staff }) {
      const gridRef = useRef();
      const defaultColDef = {
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true,
      };
    
      const [columnDefs] = useState([
        { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'first_name' },
        { headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'last_name' },
        { headerName: 'Job Title', field: 'job_title' },
        { field: 'office' },
        { field: 'email' },
        { field: 'phone' },
      ]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <main>
            <div style={{ height: '600px' }}>
              <AgGridReact
                id='staff_grid'
                ref={gridRef}
                rowData={staff}
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                rowSelection={'single'}
                style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
              ></AgGridReact>
            </div>
          </main>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    // This gets called on every request
    export async function getServerSideProps() {
      const staff = [];
    
      for (let id = 1; id <= 3; id++) {
        staff.push({
          id: id,
          first_name: 'first' + id,
          last_name: 'last' + id,
          email: 'member' + id + '@company.com',
          phone: '12345' + id,
          office: 'place' + id,
          job_title: 'Worker ' + id,
        });
      }
    
      // Pass data to the page via props
      return { props: { staff } };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Diving deep into the ag-grid's `node_modules` abyss and into their [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/), I found that their grid component is being injected into the DOM (client-side) once an "AG Grid" wrapper component has been mounted. Therefore, this is a client-side only component.

---

#### Debugging

When I request the Next page from Postman, I see an empty div where the grid should be:
[image]

But when I request the page from the browser, I see the grid:
[image]

An even easier way to determine that this is a **client-side only** component would be to assign the grid a `debug` prop:

```
<AgGridReact
  debug
  rowData={staff}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  rowSelection="single"
/>
```

We see AG Grid debug logs in the browser (Notice the `Rendered on Client` message):
[image]

But, we don't see any AG Grid debug logs on the server (Notice the `Rendered on Server` message):
[image]

#### More investigation

I thought I found a server-side rendering solution via their [Row Models](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-models/), but unfortunately it's not referring to the table being SSR'd, but the data being lazy loaded via dynamically fetching data from a server. My guess as to why this table is client-side only is that AG Grid doesn't use a native [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), but instead a bunch of `div` elements with custom styles to represent a table. Since the server doesn't have a DOM (eg, can't access `document` nor `window`), calculating these dynamic styles wouldn't be possible.

#### Alternatives

If you're creating this table for an enterprise and it's absolutely vital to have this page SSR'd for SEO, then I'd recommend having some sort of bot detection in Next's [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) and within gSSP. Then pass an `isBot` prop to the component and conditionally render a native table (styling won't matter since it's mainly used for SEO). We do something similar for our web application where search results need to be baked into the page on the server, but can be lazy-loaded client-side for a snappier UX.

Here's a working [demo](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-bot-detection). You can change the User-Agent using your browser's tools or by changing it within the request headers.

A more comprehensive bot list can be found [here](https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents/blob/master/crawler-user-agents.json).

What a user sees:
[image]

What a bot sees:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do I view the page as a bot?

Comment: Depends on the browser. in Chrome, you'll be able to change the User Agent via [Network Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent/). In Firefox, you can change it via the responsive the "Responsive Design Mode" button (at the top, after the "No throttling" option, you'll see a "UA" field -- see 2nd to last screenshot above).